# Looking for a simpler solution to this problem

Tags: java, data-structures, logic

Problem:
From the given map of bucket and its items, i need to identify if there are at least three buckets with unique items.

Notes:

1. 1 bucket can have more than one items
2. Total number of buckets could be anything between 0 - 100
3. Unique items will be among item1, item2, item3 only.

Sample data:

```
Map<String, List<String>> buckets = new HashMap<>();

        // sample data 1 - expected output -> true
        buckets.put("b1", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        buckets.put("b2", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        buckets.put("b3", Arrays.asList("item1"));
        
        System.out.println("sample 1: "+ isUniqueBucketsAndItemFound(buckets));
        
        Map<String, List<String>> bucket2 = new HashMap<>();
        
        // sample data 2 - expected output -> false because there are no unique buckets for 2,3
        bucket2.put("b1", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        bucket2.put("b2", Arrays.asList("item1"));
        bucket2.put("b3", Arrays.asList("item1"));
        
        System.out.println("sample 2: "+ isUniqueBucketsAndItemFound(bucket2));
```

Solution that i tried below which actually works. However looking for more simpler solution to avoid iterations if possible,

```
private static boolean isUniqueBucketsAndItemFound(Map<String, List<String>> buckets) {
        
        //handle basic negative cases null/empty/ size<3 etc
        
        List<List<String>> perumatations = new ArrayList<>();
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item1", "item3", "item2"));
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item2", "item1", "item3"));
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item2", "item3", "item1"));
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item3", "item1", "item2"));
        perumatations.add(Arrays.asList("item3", "item2", "item1"));
        
        for(List<String> items : perumatations) {
            System.out.println("iteration: "+ items);
            boolean isItem1Found = false;
            boolean isItem2Found = false;
            boolean isItem3Found = false;
            
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> bucket : buckets.entrySet()) {
                List<String> currentItems = bucket.getValue();
                
                if(!isItem1Found && currentItems.contains(items.get(0))) {
                    isItem1Found = true;
                } else if(!isItem2Found && currentItems.contains(items.get(1))) {
                    isItem2Found = true;
                } else if(!isItem3Found && currentItems.contains(items.get(2))) {
                    isItem3Found = true;
                }
                
                if(isItem1Found && isItem2Found && isItem3Found) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach that tries allocating up to one item per bucket and backtracks if it's unable to allocate the remaining items to the remaining buckets:

```
private static boolean isUniqueBucketsAndItemFound(Map<String, List<String>> buckets) {
    Set<String> items = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
    return search(items, new ArrayList<>(buckets.values()), 0);
}

private static boolean search(Set<String> items, List<List<String>> buckets, int offset) {
    // allocated all unique items?
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    
    for (int i = offset; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
        for (String item : buckets.get(i)) {
            // found unique item?
            if (items.remove(item)) {
                // search remaining items in remaining buckets
                if (search(items, buckets, i + 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                // restore popped item
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // out of buckets
    return false;
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/ay3rvt)

It's possible to optimize the search by sorting buckets and removing duplicates in the first method, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.